# Django render third argument

Tags: python, django, render

I am confused with Django renderring. I usually used context and dictionary in the third argument:

```
return render(request,'zing_it/home.html', context=my_playlists)
```

However, in the code below the third argument used list name in strings and list name as a variable. Can you please help me to understand what is my_playlists (in strings) and the second my_playlists (variable). Why so?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
my_playlists=[
        {"id":1,"name":"Car Playlist","numberOfSongs":4},
        {"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2}
    ]

def home(request):
    return render(request,'zing_it/home.html',{"my_playlists":my_playlists})
```

Comment: You're free to name a variable whatever you like... what is your actual question?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing but instead of creating the dictionary as a variable, they're just passing a dictionary constant.

Comment: I appologize. I had a mistake in my question and I have updated it.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's not quite the same. The first one is passing a list as the context (I assume). The second one correctly passes a dictionary.

Comment: I have added an answer and I try to cover it as simply as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the dictionary as context as well.

On your case `context = {"my_playlists":my_playlists}`

**You can add context as a variable first and then assign the value to render function like below:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

my_playlists = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Car Playlist", "numberOfSongs": 4},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Coding Playlist", "numberOfSongs": 2}
]

def home(request):
    context = {
        "my_playlists": my_playlists
    }
    return render(request, 'zing_it/home.html', context)
```

**You can do the same thing using the inline how you did. You can update it with:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
my_playlists=[
        {"id":1,"name":"Car Playlist","numberOfSongs":4},
        {"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2} ]

def home(request):
    return render(request,'zing_it/home.html',context={"my_playlists":my_playlists})
```

**As you can see there are many ways to do the same thing but it's up to you which one you like but better to follow the same pattern to maintain code easily.**

*Also, in the context this is key value pair as it's a dictionary. The first on left side is the key and right one is the value. Left which is a Key that will be used on your templates to access the model data or any data you want to have there as per your need.You can pass multiple key:value via context.*

Comment: Can you please help me to understand what is my_playlistsn (in strings) and the second my_playlists as a variable?

Comment: Definitely.  So here {"my_playlists":my_playlists}  on the left side "my_playlists" is the key which works like a variable on a template to get data, you can name this anything you like and whatever name you give you need to use that on your template to render data.
 And on the right side my_playlists is the data that you want to pass with the key variable. This is generally data comes from database ORM.

Answer (score 1):

`context` must be a dictionary. It cannot be a list, so the first version won't work assuming `my_playlist` is the same in both examples. Your second version works because it passes a dictionary correctly.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand what is my_playlistsn (in strings) and the second my_playlists as a variable?

Comment: @DavidDavid To understand this, you must look at a little bit more of that line: `{"my_playlists":my_playlists}`. The `{}` around this means this is a dictionary. The `"my_playlists"` string is a key in that dictionary and the `my_playlists` value is a the value which will be associated with that key. I recommend that you read more about dictionaries in python to understand this better.